# Handle explorer drag&drop

Tags: c#, .net, windows, drag-and-drop, shell-extensions

I am trying to make an application that detects file drag&drop operation betwen windows explorers. So it can be prevent windows copy and get droped file list and copy these files to droped target location. How can do this? Thanks.

Comment: Im not sure you probably can. for sure

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to prevent copy, paste and delete file from the determined directory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5231265/how-to-prevent-copy-paste-and-delete-file-from-the-determined-directory)

Comment: How about using a `FileSystemWatcher` to monitor the directory for new files being added?

Comment: it doesn't work for me. Because when user drop files in a directory, windows shouldn't copy files to this location. I want to do it with my own application. So there is no changes in the file system when these happens.